# Swift date generation issue

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to convert the date using the date formatter class but while calling it from the viewDidLoad method or viewWillAppear, the value comes out to be nil. Problem is if I execute a break point inside the static function, it is returning the value but that value is not reaching my viewDidLoad and sets the current date to nil. Below are the code snippet:

**Static Function**

```
static func formatDateAsPerLocalDevice(inputDate:Date) -> Date!{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar.current
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: inputDate)
    let convertedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDate)!
    return convertedDate
}
```

**View Did Load Snippet**

```
let currentDate = AppCommons.formatDateAsPerLocalDevice(inputDate: Date())
    tkCalendarState?.currentDate = currentDate
    tkCalendarState?.selectedDate = currentDate
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by converting a `Date` to a `Date`? If all you are trying to do is set it to "midnight" local time then there is a much simpler way.

Comment: correct. I just want the date for the comparison to work appropriately. Seems like @flanker just provided the answer to it below

Comment: But i think the problem still remains, even if i put in the logic to get the start of the day then too i am not able to get the value for currentDate post execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be converting a date to a string and then back to a date?  The only reason I can think of for doing this would be drop the time components and get the start of the day date/time.  In which case this is far easier:

```
let midnight = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out the issue.
Used the answer by @flanker above and changed the method signature from Date! to Date

```
static func formatDateAsPerLocalDevice(inputDate:Date) -> Date{
    return Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: inputDate)
}
```